# How to enforce maximum string length and allowed characters in protocol buffer?

Tags: validation, protocol-buffers

I am working with protocol buffers to integrate two systems. I want proto file to be contract between those systems. I see no way to put some constraints on `string` type:

- maximum length
- minimum length
- allowed characters

How to enforce (or at least document) those rules in .proto files?

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to force it, but you can document by putting standard C comments `/* comment */` . That's what I do to describe some fields of my messages.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that I have to enforce it further down in the application- using Java validation framework or other means.